# Stack in cpp is creating infinity loop

Tags: c++, stack

```
vector<vector<int>> floodFill(vector<vector<int>>& image, int sr, int sc, int color) {
    int prevColor = image[sr][sc];
    int m = image.size();
    int n = image[0].size();
    image[sr][sc] = color;
   
    stack <pair<int, int>> positionToVisit; 
    positionToVisit.push({sr, sc});

   int t = 3000;  
    while (!positionToVisit.empty() && t--) {  //There is a problem I couldn't solve, except giving t is getting time limit error
        
        if (sr>0 && image[sr-1][sc] == prevColor ) {
            image[sr-1][sc] = color;
            positionToVisit.push({sr-1, sc});
        }
        if (sr<m-1 && image[sr+1][sc] == prevColor ) {
            image[sr+1][sc] = color;
            positionToVisit.push({sr+1, sc});
        }

        if (sc>0 && image[sr][sc-1] == prevColor ) {
            image[sr][sc-1] = color;
            positionToVisit.push({sr, sc-1});
        }
        if (sr<n-1 && image[sr][sc+1] == prevColor ) {
            image[sr][sc+1] = color;
            positionToVisit.push({sr, sc+1});
        }
        
        sr = positionToVisit.top().first;
        sc = positionToVisit.top().second;
        
        image[sr][sc] = color;
        positionToVisit.pop();

    }

    return image;
}
```

If I don't use the 't' variable in the while() condition, it falls in time limit exceeded and it is not stopping when stack getting empty and continuing infinity loop. But when I'm using t here it immediately breaks when the stack is being empty. I couldn't figure out the problem.

Comment: First: Please provide an [mre] Secondly have you checked if the collection ever is empty?

Comment: Just eyeballing it as I cannot run the code, you will always be left with one element in the stack

Comment: @LarsNielsen Yeah I have printed the size of stack, it becomes size = 0 at time but still isn't breaking the while loop. Even if I hardcode like, 

if (positionToVisit.size() == 0) return image;

it doesn't help.

Comment: It is solved, I missed a case. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1):

That code looks correct except

```
if (sr<n-1 && image[sr][sc+1] == prevColor )
```

should be

```
if (sc<n-1 && image[sr][sc+1] == prevColor )
```

Comment: ohh, sorry for the typo, still it is getting TLE for infinite loop.

Comment: It is solved, I missed a case. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add this check to the beginning of your function.

```
if(color == prevColor) {
  return image;
}
```

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thanks, I overlooked that case.